# not able to create django projects

Tags: django, django-admin

When I run `django-admin.py startproject site` it opens django-admin.py` file in a text editor . The paths have been set correctly. I have previously created projects but no clue what happened now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your file association for .py files to `python.exe`.

If you are on Windows, right click on any .py file, choose open with -> default program. Select `python.exe`, also make sure you checked on that checkbox below "always use the selected program to open this kind of file".

Answer (score 0):

Your file association for .py files [has been mutilated](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-November/1074533.html). Repair or reinstall.